# Nuxt 3 Add a folder with JSON files to the build for read using `fs`

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

The project has a `data` folder where many json files with configurations are stored. Depending on the api request (which is built into nuxt 3), I read a certain JSON file (using `fs`) and output the result with additional data. In development mode it works, but in production the folder with json files is not saved. How can I upload a folder to the build?

Comment: Use public folder to serve static files. Those files will be public available. So if you don't want people to find them, hide them under a folder where the name is a generated hash so no one can find it.

Comment: @Mises not really a good solution, too easy to brute-force. Where are you hosting it? Using SSG or SSR? Or something else?

Comment: @kissu Well I hope he don't want to have there sensitive informations. But he wants it works like that.

Comment: There are other ways, like hosting it somewhere safe.

Comment: @kissu VPS, SSR

Comment: @Mises, how does the public folder works? does it require to register it on the nuxt config file? I tried but it looks like it did not work for me. I am facing a no such file error during deployment but not on development. Thanks

Comment: @RMD Files in public folder are automatically transferred to an `.output/public` folder, where your full SPA app ends up.

Comment: @Mises, it was a stupid mistake of mine, that is way it did not work. Now, it is working.  I am planning on storing the email template on the public folder but as mentioned by kissu, it would be too easy for brute-force.

Comment: @RMD If there is no way to check for hacker what exactly you host and there is only brute force to find files. If you add 128bit hash to a folder name or file. The best super computer in our world will find the correct path after a few billion years trying. We're talking about 2^128 number of combinations, it's 3.4 with an "." shifted to the right by 38 digits.

Comment: @Mises, that make sense. thank you! no sensitive data will be store on the email template though. Thank you for the idea! :D

Comment: @RMD 16char password last column is what I was talking about in this picture https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5ffe234606e5ec7bfc57a7a3/175e6393-2500-4a0d-81e8-c380bbe896e7/Hive+Systems+Password+Table?format=1000w its 92bilion years to crack.

Answer (score 1):

You could try importing the json files instead of reading with fs.

```
import data from './folder/file.json' assert { type: 'json' }
```

That should help the bundler to know these files need to be included.

Comment: I need something else, I import by custom path depending on the request.
Example: `fs.readFile(\`./data/${type}.json\`)`

Comment: You could still import all .json files and put them in an object. Then you can do `const response = jsonObjs[type]`. Or import during runtime, but I'm not sure if that's a good practice.